# implementing RNN with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement the recurrent neural network with numpy.

My current input and output designs are as follow:

`x` is of shape: (sequence length, batch size, input dimension)

`h` : (number of layers, number of directions, batch size, hidden size)

`initial weight`: (number of directions, 2 * hidden size, input size + hidden size)

`weight`: (number of layers -1, number of directions, hidden size, directions*hidden size + hidden size)

`bias`: (number of layers, number of directions, hidden size)

I have looked up pytorch API of RNN the as reference (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=rnn#torch.nn.RNN), but have slightly changed it to include initial weight as input. (output shapes are supposedly the same as in pytorch)

While it is running, I cannot determine whether it is behaving right, as I am inputting randomly generated numbers as input.

In particular, I am not so certain whether my input shapes are designed correctly.

Could any expert give me a guidance?

```
def rnn(xs, h, w0, w=None, b=None, num_layers=2, nonlinearity='tanh', dropout=0.0, bidirectional=False, training=True):
    num_directions = 2 if bidirectional else 1
    batch_size = xs.shape[1]
    input_size = xs.shape[2]
    hidden_size = h.shape[3]
    hn = []
    y = [None]*len(xs)

    for l in range(num_layers):
        for d in range(num_directions):
            if l==0 and d==0:
                wi = w0[d, :hidden_size,  :input_size].T
                wh = w0[d, hidden_size:,  input_size:].T
                wi = np.reshape(wi, (1,)+wi.shape)
                wh = np.reshape(wh, (1,)+wh.shape)
            else:
                wi = w[max(l-1,0), d, :,  :hidden_size].T
                wh = w[max(l-1,0), d, :,  hidden_size:].T
            for i,x in enumerate(xs):
                if l==0 and d==0:
                    ht = np.tanh(np.dot(x, wi) + np.dot(h[l, d], wh) + b[l, d][np.newaxis])
                    ht = np.reshape(ht,(batch_size, hidden_size)) #otherwise, shape is (bs,1,hs)
                else:
                    ht = np.tanh(np.dot(y[i], wi) + np.dot(h[l, d], wh) + b[l, d][np.newaxis])
                y[i] = ht
            hn.append(ht)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    y = np.reshape(y, y.shape+(1,))
    return np.asarray(y), np.asarray(hn)
```

Comment: If you are trying to determine if it is learning then you should use a dataset and see if it minimizes the objective. Basically the first step of debugging a model.

Comment: @David any simple dummy data to test it on?

Comment: You could check UCI, but a simple one might just be to see if it can learn addition (i.e. 1->2->3...)

Comment: @David but how would it fit into the input design above? For example, if you were to learn addition, how should it fit into the x shape of (seq_len, batch_size, input_size) and what should the outcomes be like?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an RNN without knowing what machine learning is or having even done a simple classifier first?

Comment: @David obviously I'm confused as to how to set up the shape. Depressing to see a condescending reply.

Comment: Learning addition would simply be feeding 1 into the model and then the model should spit out 2. That gets fed back in and the model spits out 3, etc. Your comment makes it clear that you are missing something about how RNNs work since it seems that you didn't understand what learning addition meant.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the shape, it probably makes sense if that's how PyTorch does it, but the Tensorflow way is a bit more intuitive - `(batch_size, seq_length, input_size)` - `batch_size` sequences of `seq_length` length where each element has `input_size` size. Both approaches can work, so I guess it's a matter of preferences.

To see whether your rnn is behaving appropriately, I'd just print the hidden state at each time step, run it on some small random data (e.g. 5 vectors, 3 elements each) and compare the results with your manual calculations.

Looking at your code, I'm unsure if it does what it's supposed to, but instead of doing this on your own based on an existing API, I'd recommend you read and try to replicate [this awesome tutorial from wildml](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) (in part 2 there's a pure numpy implementation).